# Error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I am writing a webscraping code and I am getting the above error.

```
import requests
import lxml
import bs4

title = ''
date = ''
text = ''
top = []
link = []  


web_link = 'https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/{}/'
web_link = web_link.format('india')
req = requests.get(web_link)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'lxml')
topi = soup.find('div', {'class':'main-content'})
topi = topi.find_all('span', {'class':'w_tle'})
for i in range(len(topi)):
   top = topi[i].find('a').get('href')
   link.append('https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com' + top)
for i in range(len(link)):
   rq = requests.get(link[i])
   sp = bs4.BeautifulSoup(rq.text, 'lxml')
   title = sp.find('div', {'class':'_2NFXP'})
   title = title.find('h1',{'class':'_23498'})
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xxx\xxx\py\so65702068.py", line 26, in <module>
    title=title.find('h1',{'class':'_23498'})
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'
```

I am new to web scraping and I am not understanding why is it showing this error.

Comment: Looks like the previos instruction - `title = sp.find('div', {'class':'_2NFXP'})` - failed, so `title` is `None` when executing `title = title.find('h1',{'class':'_23498'})`. By the way, please also post the errormessage/traceback - I did that for you here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try learning from your errors yourself. Python errors also specify the error's location(line).

Anyway, your last line is causing the problem. You basically applied `sp.find()` function on another `sp.find()` function.
As `sp.find('div',{'class':'_2NFXP'})` returns `None` , it justifies the error you got.

Comment: Thank You So much!  Actually I am really new so thats why I am having problems.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. If you want to maximize learning efficiency for next time, Python's error guidance is very helpful and easy to understand for beginners. Good luck!

Comment: Ok sure . I will improve myselt.